# failed to create new file in pycharm using open

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I tried to create a empty file using `open` in pycharm, and it failed to create one without complaining anything

In Pycharm

```
fw = open("sample.txt", "w")
fw.write("what's up")
fw.close()
```

I used the same code in terminal, and it successfully created the sample.txt file.

Do I have to do some configuration in Pycharm in order to make it work?

Comment: the current directory is probably write protected, and different from the one in your terminal. Check it using `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Are you checking in the correct directory for the file?  Maybe it is creating the file and the directory is different than what you think it actually is.  Try an os.getcwd() (after import os of course) and see what you get.

Comment: I got something like this `/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/bin`

Comment: I cd to the directory, and find my sample.txt under the bin directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because you are using a relative path in
`fw = open("sample.txt", "w")`

Try putting an absolute path like `fw = open("/path/to/sample.txt", "w")`.

I am saying "I guess" because the error description and the stack trace are the clues to find the problem, so you should check them and always provide them when asking for help.